Recover Funds from Failed Contract
How can I recover my funds from a failed contract? The transaction ID is 0xdbdc42e7287c51dc49a4c0ba66dca106bcb2abe7e3337214a490fb82069bd300.
Thanks,
Dave

Why do you think something has failed? I don't see any issues. You have sent 0.8 Ether to a contract, and that contract's source code is not visible in Etherscan.

You should share your contract code at least.
